# En los modelos de Django, ¿qué diferencia hay entre "default", "null" y "blank"?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, django-models

Existen diferentes maneras de configurar un campo de un modelo en Django y con frecuencia me confundo con las siguientes:

- `blank=True`
- `null=True`
- `default=0`

¿Cuál es su diferencia? Si quiero que algo no esté nunca vacío, ¿cuál debo usar?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4384098/1983854

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En [Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/) está documentado y añado mis propias traducciones al respecto:

- [Field.NULL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

  Si es True, Django guardará los valores vacíos como NULL en la base de datos. Por defecto está en False.

  Las cadenas vacías siempre se guardarán como cadenas vacías, no como NULL. Solamente usa `null=True` para campos que no sean de cadenas, como por ejemplo enteros, booleanos y fechas. Para esos tipos, también deberás definir `blank=True` si quieres permitir valores vacíos en formularios, pues el campo `null` solo afecta el almacenamiento en base de datos.
- [Field.blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank)

  Si es True, el campo puede dejarse en blanco. Por defecto está en False.

  Nótese que esto es diferente de `null`. `null` se refiere a bases de datos, mientras que `blank` es para validaciones. Si un campo tiene `blank=True`, la validación en el sitio de Django admin permitirá que se añada un campo vacío. Si el campo tiene `blank=False`, el campo será requerido.
- [Field.default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default)

  El valor por defecto del campo. Puede ser un valor o un objeto llamable. Si es llamable, se llamará cada vez que un objeto nuevo sea creado.

Así, resumiendo:

- Usa "default" para definir el valor que se dará a un campo si tu código no lo define.
- Usa "blank" para validaciones de formulario. `blank=True` permite que el campo se deje en blanco.
- Usa "null" si quieres guardar valores vacíos como NULL en la base de datos.

<sub>Respuesta basada en distintas respuestas a [In Django models.py, what's the difference between default, null, and blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4384098/1983854)</sub>